# Why does Ubuntu 14.04 LTS HVM not have CAP_AUDIT_READ?

Tags: kernel

I'm running the AWS EC2 Ubuntu 14.04 LTS HVM AMI and it is lacking CAP_AUDIT_READ when I check `man capabilities`. Any idea what's up with this? I think CAP_AUDIT_READ was added in linux kernel 3.16 and Ubuntu 14.04 is on kernel 4.2, so this is confusing.

Comment: I think it's a bug in libcap2.

Comment: fixed in `libcap2 - 1:2.25-1`